# How to find next firstResponder on controlTextDidEndEditing in NSTextField

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, first-responder

I have a custom `NSTextField` and I need to know which control is "active" when/after `controlTextDidEndEditing` is fired. The FirstResponder of the window is still on the TextField when controlTextDidEndEditing is called.

Comment: Do you want to know the control which ended editing or the control that will become active next? The next control depends on the event (tab, shift-tab, enter, mousedown, arrows), user preferences (Full Keyboard Access) and other conditions.

Comment: The next one and as I said, it's a custom control and it will be implemented in several windows … and I'd like to keep it universal. All I need to make sure that the new first responder is not a certain control

Comment: That's a different question. Do you want to disable this certain control? Maybe you should explain what you want to accomplish.

Comment: What I try is to create a Custom ComboBox as NSComboBox is very limited  and I need certain features for that. So I have a NSTextField and a NSTableView(inside a NSScrollView). On controlTextDidEndEditing I try to close the tableView (if open) … this works fine except for the case that something is done in the TableView. And therefore I need to check what control is the firstResponder after the TextField is no longer FirstResponder.

Comment: What I currently do is that I have an iVar `lostFocus` which is always `true` except for the cases that the action/doubleAction-Selector of the didChangeSelection of the TableView is called, then it's set to false.
In `controlTextDidEndEditing` I check of `lostFocus` if it's true, then the tableView will be closed otherwise it stays open.

Comment: NSComboBox uses a sheet, clicks in the tableview don't cause `controlTextDidEndEditing` of the text field. If you don't want a sheet, scheduling a block or method on the main thread to check the first responder and close the tableview might work. Use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)` or `- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;` `delay` = 0.

Comment: As I said, I don't use `NSComboBox` as it does not offer features I need and the sheet can't be configured like I need it. E.g. I need separators which can't be selected.
Therefore I used a `NSTextField` and mimic the behaviour of the `NSComboBox`.
In `controTextlDidEndEditing` I hide the TableView. This behaves as it should except when a `TableViewCell` is selected. Because `controlTextDidEndEditing` is called BEFORE the action of the TableView is called.
What I tried to achieve is to find out the either reason why `controlTextDidEndEditing` is called or the next firstResponder

Comment: If you want to imitate `NSCombobox` you could also use a sheet. Don't try to predict the new first responder. Let Cocoa pick the new first responder and next hide the tableview.

Comment: I'm a bit curious, how would you achieve that with a sheet? Do you have some sample code?

Comment: It turns out to be a child window. Sample code: [CustomMenus](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CustomMenus/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the object that is accessible via the key `_NSFirstResponderReplacingFieldEditor` in the notifications userInfo.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using undocumented keys.